# loopback api returning error AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am having two models : user and car

user acl :

```
 "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "find"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "login"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
```

car acl :

```
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "find"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
```

I am able to add car using api `/cars` but unable to get list of cars using api `/cars`  , during get it is returning `AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED` error code.

note : i am logged in as a user then i am trying to get list of cars owned by user.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're missing to add the model relation in agreement with [Loopback documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html#dynamic-roles):

> To qualify a $owner, the target model needs to have a belongsTo relation 
>   to the User model (or a model extends from User) and property matching 
>   the foreign key of the target model instance.  The check for $owner is 
>   only performed for a remote method that has ‘:id’ on the path, for 
>   example, GET /api/users/:id.

Also I believe it would be a good idea change the [default setting](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/config.json.html) `aclErrorStatus` from **401** to **403**. This way it would be easier to understand if it's an issue with *authentication* or *authorization*.